# Stop SQL Server Express remotely with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use the following line:

```
 Set-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS' -Status Stopped -PassThru -ComputerName '123.123.45.67'
```

...but receive this error:
Set-Service : Cannot stop service 'SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) (MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS)' because it has dependent services.

This has to be done remotely, so I don't believe Net Stop or Stop-Service will work, as I haven't seen remote commands for it.
I have Administrator access on the calling and receiving servers.

I checked the remote machine and the only dependency of the service is: 
SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS), which is disabled.

How can I remotely shut down SQL Server Expresss and have it also shut down dependencies, like the Stop-Service -Force command?

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap `Stop-Service` inside an `Invoke-Command` block.  something like

```
Invoke-Command -Computername '123.123.45.67' -Scriptblock {Stop-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS'}
```

Your probably already aware but just in case your not you will need to make sure that the target server is in your trusted hosts list if your really using the IP in production, preferably tho use a DNS name.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered this:

```
 (get-service -ComputerName '123.123.45.67' -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS').Stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Service` uses the 'System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController' class which can operate on remote computers and can be piped to `Stop-Service`.

To stop dependant services you just need to enumerate them and then also pipe to `Stop-Service`.

```
$Service = Get-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS' -ComputerName '123.123.45.67'
$Service.DependentServices | Stop-Service -Verbose -WhatIf
$Service | Stop-Service -Verbose -WhatIf
```

Note: remove both `-WhatIf` for production.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **-Force**  parameter for stopping all the dependent services directly in powershell.

**In Powershell:**

```
Get-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS' -ComputerName '123.123.45.67' |stop-service -force –PassThru
```

**In cmd line:**

```
net stop MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS /yes
```

and it will stop all dependent services too.

Hope it helps.